# Python API sentinelsat error in download

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, sentinel1, sentinelsat

I am having a go at using the sentinelsat python API to download satellite imagery. However, I am receiving error messages when I try to convert to a pandas dataframe. This code works and downloads my requested sentinel satellite images:

```python
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt
from datetime import date

api = SentinelAPI('*****', '*****', 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus')

footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson('testAPIpoly.geojson'))

products = api.query(footprint, cloudcoverpercentage = (0,10))

#this works  
api.download_all(products)
```

However if I instead attempt to convert to a pandas dataframe

```python
#api.download_all(products)

#this does not work
products_df = api.to_dataframe(products)

api.download_all(products_df)
```

I receive an extensive error message that includes

> "sentinelsat.sentinel.SentinelAPIError: HTTP status 500 Internal Server Error: InvalidKeyException : Invalid key (processed) to access Products
>   "

(where processed is also replaced with **title**, **platformname**, **processingbaseline**, etc.). I've tried a few different ways to convert to a dataframe and filter/sort results and have received an error message every time (note: I have pandas/geopandas installed). How can I convert to a dataframe and filter/sort with the sentinelsat API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
api.download_all(products_df)
```

try

```
api.download_all(products_df.index)
```

Comment: Thanks-- this worked. From the documentation, they have `api.download_all(products_df_sorted['id'])` which returns me a "KeyError: 'id'". Why?

Comment: You are very welcome to *accept* the answer - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Done. Any idea on why the indexing from the documentation is not working?

Comment: I guess the creators of sentinelsat package meant to create a column in the dataframe named 'id' where ids  would be stored but instead ids are stored as row names (index).

Comment: The [docs](https://sentinelsat.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=products_df_sorted) point to using `api.download_all(df.index)` and have been for some time. Where did you find the example using `df['id']` @dave?

Comment: The docs were changed when the error was pointed out [here](https://github.com/sentinelsat/sentinelsat/issues/216#issuecomment-404136389)